# What is & Why do I need " Linux Vendor Firmware Service <sign@fwupd.org>" key?

Tags: gnupg, keyrings, pgp

As I was exploring and learning PGP keys, I encountered this :

When I did `root@Tux:~# gpg2 --list-keys` , I get this :

```
root@Tux:~# gpg2 --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa2048/4538BAC2 2015-07-21 [SC]
uid         [ unknown] Linux Vendor Firmware Service <sign@fwupd.org>
```

But the **Strange thing** is, when I tried the same with `gpg` (not `gpg2`) , I don't get this key. Instead I get my key and my friends keys that I added manually .

One more **point to be noted** is, this key is displayed only when logged in as **`root`**

That is , First `sudo su`, then `gpg2 --list-keys`

I tried it with some other systems too.. same result.

My question is , what is this key ? why do I get it only in `gpg2` and logged as root ?

Comment: Read this please https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2015/08/13/linux-vendor-firmware-project-we-need-your-help/

Comment: I don't have anything like that. Maybe you imported this for some PPA?

Comment: @Rinzwind nice :-) , I got to know about that project now, but I don't know when and how this key got into my system. and it being shown only under `gpg2` is strange.

Comment: @muru I removed that key and did `sudo apt-get update`, no warnings!, no errors!. I added it back ;-P

Comment: @SeverusTux so? It might still be in apt's keyring - you might have added it using `gpg --recv-keys`, export and then `apt-key add`, in which case removing it from your GPG keyring won't change anything.

Comment: @muru ah.. you are right. but I checked apt's keyring with `apt-key list` , I did not find this key :-|